# Implementing a machine learning-like optimizer

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to predict the trend of an internet post.

I have available the number of comments and votes the post has after 2 minutes of being posted (can change, but it should be enough).

Currently I use this formula:

```
predicted_votes = (votes_per_minute + n_comments * 60 * h) * k
```

And then I find `k` experimentally. I get the post data, wait an hour, do

```
k = (older_k + actual_votes/predicted_votes) / 2
```

And so on. This kind of works. The accuracy is pretty low (40 - 50%), but it gives me a rough idea on how the post is going to react.

I was wondering if I could employ a more complex equation, something like:

```
predicted_votes = ((votes_per_minute * x + n_comments * y) * 60 * hour) * k # Hour stands for 'how many hours to predict'
```

And then optimize the parameters to approximate a bit better.

I would assume that I could use Machine Learning, although I don't have a GPU available (that's right, I'm running on integrated graphics, blame Mojave), so I am trying this approach instead.

So the question boils down to, how do I optimize those parameters (`k,x,y`) to get a better accuracy?

EDIT:

I tried following what @Alexis said, and this is where I am at right now:

```
import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


 initial_votes_list = [1.41, 0.9, 0.94, 0.47, 0]
 initial_comment_list = [0, 3, 0, 1, 64]

 def func(x, k, t, s):
      votes_per_minute = x[0]
      n_comments = x[1]
      return ((votes_per_minute * t + n_comments * s) * 60) * k



 xdata = [1.41,0]
 y = func(xdata, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
 np.random.seed(1729)
 ydata = y + 5
 plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')

 popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

 plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'g--',
          label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

 plt.xlabel('Time')
 plt.ylabel('Score')
 plt.legend()
 plt.show()
```

I am not sure how to feed the data I have (votes_per_minute, n_comments), nor how I could tell the algorithm that `y` axis is actually time.

EDIT 2:

Tried doing what @Alexis told me, but I am unsure what to use as `actual_score`, a number doesn't work, a list neither.. Also, I want to predict the 'score' not the number of comments.

```
import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

 initial_votes_list = [1.41, 0.9, 0.94, 0.47, 0]
 initial_comment_list = [0, 3, 0, 1, 64]

 final_score = [26,12,13,14,229]

 def func(x,k,t,s):
     return ((x[0]*k+x[1]*t)*60*x[2])*s
 X = [[a,b,c] for a,b,c in zip(initial_votes_list,initial_comment_list,[i for i in range(len(initial_votes_list))])]
 y = actual_votes # What is this?

 popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, X, y)

 plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'g--',
          label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

 plt.xlabel('Time')
 plt.ylabel('Score')
 plt.legend()
 plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need ML to do so (overkill i think here). Scipy provides a nice and easy way to fit a curve to the observations you have.

[scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) allows you to fit a function with unknown parameters to your observation. As you already know the general form of the function, optimizing the hyper parameters is a well known stat problem and thus scipy should be enough.

We can take a small example to demonstrate this:
first we generate the datas

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
>>>
>>> def func(x, a, b, c):
...     return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
```

Define the data to be fit with some noise:

```
>>> xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
>>> y = func(xdata, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
>>> np.random.seed(1729)
>>> y_noise = 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=xdata.size)
>>> ydata = y + y_noise
>>> plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')
```

then we fit the function (ax+b=y) to the data using scipy:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
```

you could add constraints to this, but for your problem it is not necessary. 
By the way, this example is at the end of the link i provided. Everything you should know to use the curve fit is available on this page.

**Edit**

it seems you have a hard time figuring out how to use this. Let's go slowly and analytically to make sure we are ok every step of the way:

- you want to predict the number of comment, this is your `y`. It is known. not calculated
- you have in entry three parameters: the `votes_per_minute` , the `n_comments` and the hour h
- and last but not least, you have three parameters to a function `(x,y,k)`

so `X[i]` (one sample) should look like this: `[votes_per_minute,n_comments,h]` 
and with your formula y = ((votes_per_minute * k + n_comments * t) * 60 * h) * s, by replacing the names:

```
def func(x,k,t,s):
    return ((x[0]*k+x[1]*t)*60*x[2])*s
X = np.array([[a,b,c] for a,b,c in zip(initial_votes_list,initial_comment_list,[i for i in range(len(initial_votes_list))])]).T
y = score
```

and then:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, X, y)
```

(if i understand your issue...if not, i don't see where the problem is)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

initial_votes_list = [1.41, 0.9, 0.94, 0.47, 0]
initial_comment_list = [0, 3, 0, 1, 64]

final_score = [26,12,13,14,229]

def func(x,k,t,s):
    return ((x[0]*k+x[1]*t)*60*x[2])*s
X = np.array([[a,b,c] for a,b,c in zip(initial_votes_list,initial_comment_list,[i for i in range(len(initial_votes_list))])]).T
y = [0.12,0.20,0.5,0.9,1] 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, X, y)



print(popt)
>>>[-6.65969099e+00 -6.99241803e-02 -9.33412000e-04]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: The var names are not really helpful, how do I apply this to my data?

Comment: x = [votes_per_minute,n_comments] y = predicted_votes param = [x,y,h,k]

Comment: `h` stands for hour, in this case how would I use the `y` as time?

Comment: I edited the question again, it doesn't quite work yet.

Comment: y is what you want to predict. It's the value you are using for the accuracy measure as the truth.

Comment: Yes, and what I want to predict is the score of the post after one hour. Supplying a number doesn't work, and a list neither. Try for yourself.

Comment: thx for showing not effort to solve it (no error message posted, no try to solve it, no effort to understand it). a simple transpose solve it for me. i've updated the answer. And as far as i'm concerned, the initial question is solved. So please do not extend the question by updating the question. Close this one and ask a new one.

Comment: @A.Dandelion Please Please Please explain to me how you don't understand that my solution works and that a single copy past of the code fix your (**the code with the transpose works, i've tested it!**)

Comment: Please use matplotlib and plot the result. The code is in the question.

Comment: and how do you plot a 4D plot? by all mean tell me.....and the code is in the question....because i wrote it.....

Comment: How and why is the plot 4D? The plot should include the initial score at T=1 and the final score at T=2. That's it. The comment_number should only be used to enhance the prediction, it should not be displayed at all.

Comment: then i'm happy to watch you do it. I m here to help you solve an issue, i am not a free worker to whom you can assign task. "Please use matplotlib and plot the result. The code is in the question." ==> please pay me to do your job? (i am on the verge of deleting the answer)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow

Comment: You solved an issue by making another one. I have no idea how numpy works and the docs require math knowledge that I do not have. Calling me a 'bad programmer' just because I don't know numpy makes no sense.

Comment: @A.Dandelion The solution is to post a follow-up question if you run into another issue. Keeping updating the question with follow-up problems is bad and unfair to users answering: it forces them to update their answer to stay relevant to the question, in this case over _hours_. Please don't do that. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/204841